# Keras custom loss different shapes of `ypred` and `ytrue`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I would like to implement a custom loss for a model I am training. The goal of the model is to create a box which separates two classes. The output of the model is 3 floats, which define the edges of the box.

I would like a loss function that works something like this:

```
# ytrue has shape [batch, 2, 64, 64, 64]
# ypred has shape [batch, 3]
def custom_loss(ytrue, ypred):
    class0_locations = ytrue[:,0]
    class1_locations = ytrue[:,1]

    # penalize class1 outside box and class 0 inside box
    class1_outside = f1(class1_locations, ypred)
    class0_inside  = f2(class0_locations, ypred)

    return class1_outside + class0_inside
```

However, this does not work as Keras does not like losses with different shapes for `ytrue` and `ypred` (see https://keras.io/api/losses/). Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You have not explained _why_ your targets have a different shape. Presumably your targets should also be boxes defined in the same manner as the outputs.